CI/CD build image container unable to run systemd
Firstly, I am a bit of a rookie when it comes to both gitlab pipelines and docker containers, and I'm taking over a project that has been neglected for a very long time, built by someone else forever ago. I am an SRE trying to assist my developers in updating the application to run on Ubuntu 20.04, where in its current production iteration is still on Ubuntu 14. I have searched and searched and have been unable to find an answer that addresses my situation, which is...
I am building a new CI/CD pipeline in Gitlab for an application that hasn't been updated in several years. When new code is merged to master, the pipeline executes a build job that spins up a runner. The runner then pulled a container image from a Containerfile hosted in a separate repo, and uses that to start a container in which to build the application. I mention this because every other time I have seen this error addressed, the answers are to use privileged flags in the command to start the container or utilize podman from my terminal when I start the container. I can do neither since this is all automated via the gitlab runner.
That said, if there is a way to accomplish the same thing via adding a line to .gitlab-ci.yml under the build stage, that would be an acceptable solution as well, I just don't know what that would be. Here is the current build stage of that file:
build:
    stage: build
    image: [Removed for privacy, points to base docker image created by Containerfile]
    rules:
      - !reference [.run without tags, rules]
    variables:
      GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    script:
      - sudo apt-get clean
      # Run local script from repository to install salt on the build container.
      - ./salt_me.sh
      - make clean
      - make debpkg
      - mv ../*.deb .
    artifacts:
      expire_in: 3 mos
      paths: [ '*.deb', deploy.env, 'build/cov' ]
      reports:
        dotenv: deploy.env

This application is heavily dependent on postgres, so part of the testing of the build is to initialize a local database and ensure the application can communicate with it. When it builds, it calls a number of salt states, one of which includes a highstate for the database. This is where my build is failing:
[INFO    ] Running state [postgresql] at time 17:48:37.982497
[INFO    ] Executing state service.mod_watch for [postgresql]
[INFO    ] Executing command /usr/bin/systemctl in directory '/root'
[INFO    ] Executing command /usr/bin/systemctl in directory '/root'
[INFO    ] Executing command /usr/bin/systemctl in directory '/root'
[ERROR   ] Command '/usr/bin/systemctl' failed with return code: 1
[ERROR   ] stderr: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
[ERROR   ] retcode: 1

I understand that containers don't natively run systemd because they are run as a single process without the weight or access levels that systemd requires. What I need to know is if there is anything I can add to my Containerfile that will overcome that. I recognize that running the container in such a way can present security risks, but these containers are only active for the duration of the build job, after which the gitlab runner (which is on an isolated network) shuts it down and cleans it from its system to be ready for the next job.
Here's a bit of my Containerfile being used for the base image (truncated because it also installs a lot of dependencies for the application that aren't really germane to this issue):
FROM ubuntu:focal

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y tzdata git-lfs gnupg2 wget \
    && ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime \
    && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata \
    && wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list' \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests \
        [various dependencies]

RUN git config --global user.email "[removed from question]"
RUN git config --global user.name "Dyna Bot"
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash\n\$@" > /usr/bin/sudo
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/sudo

I did attempt adding the following to my Containerfile for the base image, which did not change the result at all:
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN printf '#!/bin/sh\nexit 0' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
RUN apt-get update...[the stuff that was already there up through the dependencies]

RUN printf "systemctl start systemd-logind" >> /etc/profile
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/init"]

[and then the RUN git config commands]


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

A better approach is probably to change the Salt configuration so it supports running in a Docker container.

20.04 will soon be unsupported too. Perhaps you should aim for 24.04.
